# Return all elements of nested list from a function

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function to filter out a prefix and return the elements that apply without the prefix. These elements are in a nested list.

```
def filter(uni):
    for i in uni:
      for j in i:
        if j.startswith('University'):
          new = j.replace('University of ', '') + ' University'
          return new
    return uni
```

My function only returns the first element that applies to it, how can I return all elements?

Comment: don't return when you replace the first new element.  Also provide sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
def filter(uni):
    result = []
    for i in uni:
      for j in i:
        if j.startswith('University'):
          new = j.replace('University of ', '') + ' University'
          result.append(new)
    return result
```